# TransactionRequiredException:Executing and Update/Delete query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi I'm using spring boot and getting the above exception even after using @Transactional. The structure of calls is as follows,

```
@Service
class A {

  @Transactional
  public void methodA() {
    dao.daoMethod();
  }
}

@Service
class Dao {
  public void daoMethod{
    repo.updateQuery();
  }
}

@Repository
class Repo {
@Modifying
@Query("Update table....")
void updateQuery();
}
```

I can't understand why am I getting the exception even if I'm creating a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need @Transactional, because You have used @Service.
Your structure should be like:

```java
@Repository
class Dao {
  public void daoMethod{
    repo.updateQuery();
  }
}
```

And why are you call a service from another service?

Comment: So the repo class has @Repository which is being called from the dao class. Have also updated the description to mention that.

Comment: Post your full error log also that would be helpful.